# Error CS1061: AppDelegate does not contain a definition for GetNativeField

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm writting my first iPhone app using mono touch. I have only written a little bit of code, and suddenly, it does not compile anymore, I get this error:

/MyRoute/MainWindow.xib.designer.cs(85,85): Error CS1061: Type `xxxx.AppDelegate' does not contain a definition for`GetNativeField' and no extension method `GetNativeField' of type`xxx.AppDelegate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (xxx)

Any idea where this error comes from and how to solve it?

Thanks! :-D

Edited: Added aditional information:

**THIS IS THE MAINWINDOW DESIGNER CODE:**

```
namespace GuiaTeleIphone {


    // Base type probably should be MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject or subclass
    [MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate {

        private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow __mt_window;

        #pragma warning disable 0169
        [MonoTouch.Foundation.Connect("window")]
        private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow window {
            get {
                this.__mt_window = ((MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow)(this.GetNativeField("window")));
                return this.__mt_window;
            }
            set {
                this.__mt_window = value;
                this.SetNativeField("window", value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THIS IS THE MAIN.CS:**

```
namespace GuiaTeleIphone
{
    public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args);
        }
    }

    // The name AppDelegate is referenced in the MainWindow.xib file.
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        List<RSSChannel> RemoteChannelsData;

        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // If you have defined a view, add it here:
            // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

                        // do things here

            return true;
        }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other partial class of xxxx.AppDelegate is missing or in a different namespace. It specifies the base class.

Comment: sorry mhutch. Which other partial class?

Comment: If you're using the default templates, it's probably inside Main.cs.

Comment: Hi, I think both are in the same namespace... Please have a look at the code I've added at the original post

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate has a GetNativeField method. You should verify that both class parts are being included in the build, and that there are no other classes called AppDelegate.

Comment: I don't know what happened... I just created a new solution, copied and pasted everything, and it worked... I suppose it is for some namespace madness... thanks mhutch